# Gain access to SQL Server instance to be able to set up a user that can subscribe to reports in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, credentials, subscription

I have a SQL Server instance that has been in place with our company for several years. There is an SSRS site (and reporting database) associated with it where you can run reports from. We now want to be able to Subscribe to reports from that SSRS site.

In order to do so, we need to create a data source that has stored credentials that can run the report. Those credentials need to be set up in the SSRS database I believe. Unfortunately we don't have access to the database to do so.

How can we get a report subscribed in this situation?

Comment: Create the account you need. This is fully covered in the relevant MSDN chapters. The UI also explains what is needed. The reporting service is just another client as far as the database is concerned. If the service account doens't have permissions to read from the database, you need to provide an account that can. Subscriptions run without any connected users which means the service needs to store the execution account's credentials somewhere.

Comment: Check [Configure the Unattended Execution Account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156302.aspx) and [Create and Manage Subscriptions for Native Mode Report Servers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156307.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using only the Report Manager interface.

Go to the data source for the report and check the option for "Credentials stored securely on the report server" and supply the 'User name' and 'Password'.